# How to use obtained data from serial device in flutter application in other application

Tags: flutter

I have made an application in flutter which reads data from serial device for this I have used usb_serial library.
I want the obtained value from the serial device access through all application input flied.
how can I do that in flutter.

I have obtained data from serail device but it only works when I open the application but I need the obtained data pass to the other application.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I unterstood clearly. You have 2 options.

1. Save the obtained value from the serial device in local storage. For this, you can use [Hive](https://pub.dev/packages/hive) , [Shared Preferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences)  e.t.c
2. Save the value in Provider so that you can use it anywhere in your app. You can use [Riverpod](https://pub.dev/packages/riverpod)
3. Also you can use any other package that can save your value and let it use globally. Above 2 are only my favorites.

Comment: actually what I need is keyboard wedge functionality which forward the obtained data from flutter application to any other application in android device.